# Button Material Design

Tags: android-studio, botón, material-design, androidx

Hola a alguno le pasó que el botón no efectue cambios. Estoy queriendo utilizar los atributos del Boton que trae en el Material Design. Pero no previsualizo los cambios como el Stroke, su color,y pero el boton no cambia. Si alguno me tira alguna idea de que puede ser por favor, le agradeceria.

```
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetRight="4dp"
            android:insetLeft="4dp"
            app:strokeColor="#000"
            app:strokeWidth="5dp"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

Este es el gradle

```
`dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}`
```

No tengo idea de que falta para que se realicen los cambios usando los atributos que vienen utilizando materia design.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

Por cierto, utilice BottomNavigationBar y 2 de sus atributos sin problemas.

Comment: Cambia la version de tu libreria por una version estable: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` y da clic en `Build -> Clean Project`

Comment: Lo hice y sigue todo igual.
Descargue la app que viene como muestra; llamada "Shrine".
Cuando abro la app se ve todo bien, hasta puedo poner los botones que quiera y manejar sus atributos. En cuanto me fui a otra pestaña, o me fui a windows, y vuelvo al android studio, ya no se sigue visualizando lo que hago

Comment: este problema lo tengo únicamente con los botones normales. Con radiobutton no ocurre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba que al migrar a AndroidX no cambió el estilo `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`
Lo reemplace por `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">` y ya se visualiza todo bien.